File Deleted After Update
My LibGDX game uses a single file to store settings and player progress.
This code is used to read/write the settings (try/catch has been removed to keep this post short):
public void save() {
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("archivedSettings.dat");
    file.writeBytes(serialize(archivedSettings), false);
}

private ArchivedSettings read() {
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("archivedSettings.dat");
    ArchivedSettings settings = null;
    settings = (ArchivedSettings) deserialize(file.readBytes());
    return settings;
}

private static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(obj);
        return b.toByteArray();
    }

    public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
        return o.readObject();
    }

The code works fine during normal usage. You can run the game and quit it or force quit it over and over and this code works. When updating my game via Google Play, the read method fails and the settings and progress are lost.
The updates are not in any way changing this code or the ArchivedSettings class.
Since the issue only occurs after updating the app from the Google Play store, it seems as though the file is being deleted or modified.
I have read several posts on StackOverflow and other sites. This includes:
Android App Update Internal Storage Files Deleted
Android Internal Storage when updating application
Keeping saved files of app after an update
Almost every post online says that the files are not deleted but I have tested with several different accounts on several phones and every time the file has been deleted after the update. The first post has the same issue as me but uses different code.
Would I be better off using sharedPreferences instead? Does that get deleted after an update? Do I have some sort of bug in my code that only appears after an update?
